# Is it still possible to update Ubuntu Studio using a USB?

Tags: boot, usb, updates

Is it possible to update Ubuntu Studio from 18.04 to 20.04 using a live USB without overwriting the installed programs and data. There is no option to update when I boot to the live USB. Or do I have to rely on the software update tool? If it is possible could someone tell me how? I know previous versions of Ubuntu allowed us to do that.
Thanks Ahead

Answer (score 0):

A live USB is generally used for reinstalling or fixing errors. If you just want to upgrade your system to the latest Ubuntu release, you can do so with the following command on the real system:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This command will check for a new Ubuntu version and allow you to upgrade to it if available.

However, you should be automatically prompted by the "Software Updater" to upgrade. If you are not, you should be able to launch it and see the message "New Ubuntu release 20.04 available" or something along those lines. `do-release-upgrade` should be used as a fallback if (for whatever reason) the Software Updater doesn't show the latest release.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have to do a little more poking around on my system to check if it is actually at 20.04. I do regular updates using the Software Updater tool but don't recall any message that it is installing 20.04. I run Ubuntu Studio and that is the latest LTS version from Studio.